# How to perform non-integer average pooling one a 1d numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, image-resizing

Suppose I have a 1d Numpy array with size n. How can I perform average pooling to resize the array to size m, where the factor R=n/m is non-integer. This would be equivalent to partitioning the array in non-integer bins and calculating the average on each bin. The code snippet shows the functionality I am looking for, it calculates the average on each bin and also takes array elements which are only fractionally in the bin into account.

```
result = []

bins = np.linspace(0, len(array), m+1)
for i, j in zip(bins[:-1], bins[1:]):
    i_ceil = int(np.ceil(i))
    i_diff = i_ceil - i

    j_floor = int(np.floor(j))
    j_diff = j - j_floor

    numerator = np.sum(array[i_ceil:j_floor]) + array[max(0, i_ceil-1)] * i_diff + array[min(len(array)-1, j_floor)] * j_diff

    result.append(numerator / (j-i))

assert np.mean(np.array(result)) == np.mean(array)
return np.array(result)
```

Comment: You may need to refer to the `stride` and `padding` in CNN.

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches:

1. to split `[0, 1 .. n-1]` into exactly `m` non-overlapping pieces,
   see [Bresenham's_line_algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm):
   `m` horizontal line segments make a balanced split,
   see the picture. This is probably overkill.
2. smooth the `n` data points, resample at `m`.
   For example with `n = 101, m = 10`, filter all the data with
   [np.convolve](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html)
   or
   [scipy.signal.lfilter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter.html)
   or
   [filtfilt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.filtfilt.html) ...
   then take `yfiltered[[5, 15 .. 95]]`.
   (There's a huge literature on resampling / compressing audio and video signals,
   over 800 [dsp.stack questions/tagged/compression](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compression) .)

Bytheway [np.split](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) is nice.